# What Kind of Multisig Wallet Is This?

Tags: wallets, multisignature

I came across a really interesting scam when someone sent me an NFT that was a picture of a wallet seed phrase and a wallet interface with several thousand dollars in it which really made me laugh. Curiosity got the better of me and so I imported the wallet and sure enough there was a large sum of USDT. This was on the TRX chain, and of course there was no TRX in the wallet. I really wanted to understand the scam so I sent a small amount of TRX to the wallet to see what would happen when I tried to move to the funds. Sure enough I got an error. I googled the error and it said that this usually means that multiple signatures are required to move the funds. Clever, right?

But I don't understand how this is possible. If I were to create a multisignature wallet on Ethereum, I would write a smart contract to handle that logic. But in this case, I simply imported a seed phrase which derived a key. So my question is: What kind of a multi-signature wallet is this, and how does one go about generating one?

Comment: Sounds a bit weird. But I've given up trying to understand how Tron works, since it seems to have all sorts of weird stuff happening.

Comment: It's very weird indeed!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that TRX accounts can be configured with different permissions and weights for different actions, sort of like EOS accounts. So although you may have the private key, you cannot actually send a transaction due to those permission settings.

[enter link description here](https://developers.tron.network/docs/multi-signature)